# I'm new to Java, what does it mean for while(t!=-1) [READFILE]?

Tags: java, readfile

I'm new to Java and I'm learning how to read file from .txt. I've stumbled across numerous notes from my lecture and I'm just wondering why it has to be while(t!=-1) when I'm trying to read a file from my small and simple java code.

Thanks for the answers. :)

EDIT: Thank you guys for the answer. I understand that -1 means the end-of-file, so the loop will continue until the file is completely read. But does it have to be -1? Is it some kind of specific rule in Java? Thank you.

```
import java.io.*;
public class test2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
FileReader inone = new FileReader("myfile.txt");
int t=inone.read();
while (t!=-1) {
    System.out.print((char)t);
    t=inone.read();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: != is "not equal to". At a guess when reading a file, it will return -1 when it reaches the end of the file

Comment: Thank you, I understand that but why must it be -1? Is it a specific rule in Java for end-of-file?

Comment: [Read the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read()): "[returns] -1 if the end of the stream has been reached"

Comment: Thank you Andy Turner, but I would like to know why does it has to be -1?

Comment: It's just what the API returns, if it returns a positive value, it tends to mean that's how many bytes it read ...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about the loop that reads file contents.

Usually it looks like:

```
while (int symbol = inputStreamRef.read()!=-1) {
   // do something
}
```

`inputStreamRef` is an [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) subclass object.

`inputStreamRef.read()` - reads the file, and returns `-1` when end of file has been reached.

`while (symbol != -1)` means that end of file has not been reached and we need to continue reading the file contents.

---

**UPDATE**

According to the code you've posted, check my comments:

```
// you are initializing the reader for the file
FileReader inone = new FileReader("myfile.txt");

// reading the first byte to the 't' variable
int t=inone.read();

// if file is empty, 't' will contain -1
// and loop won't start
while (t!=-1) {
   // if t does not contain -1, then end of file is not reached
   // printing byte
   System.out.print((char)t);

   // reading the next byte
   t=inone.read();
}
```

Comment: So the while(t!=-1) in the code means that as long as it's not at the end of the file, keep reading? Thanks.

Comment: @Ken yes, I've updated my answer. Until code gets `-1` it should continue, because end of file is not reached yet. As end of file has been reached, read() will return `-1` and file read loop will stop working.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know as well, why does it have to be -1? Is it a specific rule in Java for eof? Thank you :)

Comment: @Ken I've posted an update to my answer with comments to your code. Regarding your question about -1, it is the general contract for `read()` method. It return `-1` when end of file has been reached. Check [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read--) for the `read()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`while()` is a loop. It means that whatever is inside the while's braces ( `{` and `}` ) will be executed over and over again.

The statement inside the parentheses, `t != -1`, controls how many times the while will execute. In this case, it will execute as long as the variable t is not equal to -1.

That should provide you a general overview, but the more code you post the more clear we can be about what the specific while in question is doing.

Comment: Thank you for the general overview, I've included the code.